# SQL query that gives me the percentage of users that fail to run a game per day

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I'd really appreciate help on a SQL query I've been struggling to write.

**Background**:

Everytime a user plays a game, a record gets created in the table `game_runs`, along with their `user_id` and `run_date` (a MySQL timestamp).

- When the user successfully plays the game, they get a score greater than 0.
- If the game failed to run (e.g. maybe it crashed), the score is `0`

The table looks something like this:

```
 id  |     run_date         |  user_id   |   score   
-------------------------------------------------------
 1   |  2020-02-02 00:20:00 |    10      |     0      |   
 2   |  2020-02-02 01:50:10 |    10      |    40      |   
 3   |  2020-02-02 03:40:20 |    11      |    80      |   

 4   |  2020-02-03 03:20:14 |    20      |    80      |   
 5   |  2020-02-03 12:20:14 |    21      |     0      |   

 6   |  2020-02-04 06:20:42 |    50      |     0      |   
 7   |  2020-02-04 11:15:00 |    50      |     0      |
 8   |  2020-02-04 12:10:46 |    51      |    70      |   

 9   |  2020-02-05 00:15:00 |    60      |     0      |
10   |  2020-02-05 01:10:40 |    61      |     0      |
```

I would like to find out what percent of **users** fail to run the game per day.

In the above example, here's what I'm hoping I can generate:

```
date         |   percent_users_who_failed_to_run_the_game
-------------------------------------------------------------
2020-02-02   |   0
2020-02-03   |   0.5
2020-02-04   |   0.5
2020-02-05   |   1
```

Notice how on `2020-02-02`, the percent of users who failed to run the game is 0% (i.e. everyone succeeded at least once). This is because on `2020-02-02`, there were three runs:

- id=1: user_id `10` failed to run it initially (score=0)
- id=2: user_id `10` succeeds the second time (score=40)
- id=3: user_id `11` succeeds

Since both users were successful that day, the percent of users that failed was 0%.

I'd love any input on how to get started. I am using mySQL v8+ so have access to window functions if that is necessary (my research tells me that they may help, but have been unable to write a query that does this).

I think the right logic would be something along the lines of finding out the % of users that have a `MAX(score) = 0` but unsure how to write the query.

I hope that wasn't too unclear - I really appreciate you reading thus far, and any pointers will be so helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to do this in two steps. The first step is to get the maximum score per user per day:

```
SELECT  CAST(Run_Date AS DATE) AS RunDate,
        User_ID,
        MAX(Score) AS Score
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY CAST(Run_Date AS DATE), User_ID;
```

Then you can put this in a subquery and calculate your percentage:

```
SELECT  RunDate,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Score = 0 THEN 1 END) / SUM(1.0) AS Failed_Percent
FROM    (   SELECT  CAST(Run_Date AS DATE) AS RunDate,
                    User_ID,
                    MAX(Score) AS Score
            FROM    YourTable
            GROUP BY CAST(Run_Date AS DATE), User_ID
        ) AS t
GROUP BY RunDate;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb408d/8)**

You can also achieve this without a subquery using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT  CAST(Run_Date AS DATE) AS RunDate,
        1 - (1.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Score > 0 THEN User_ID END) 
            / COUNT(DISTINCT User_id)) AS Failed_Percent
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY CAST(Run_Date AS DATE);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb408d/13)**

This is really doing the reverse logic, but the result is the same. The relevant parts are:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Score > 0 THEN User_ID END)
```

This gets the total number of distinct users that ran the game successfully on any given date, Then

```
COUNT(DISTINCT User_id)
```

Gives the total number of users that logged a record on that date. The former divided by the latter gives the percent of successful users, so we then need to minus this from 1 to get the percent of failed. I have multiplied one of the counts by 1.0 to implicitly convert it to a decimal to avoid [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html)

I would expect the first query to be more efficient, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Gareth! I ran the two queries and you were right, the sub-query is indeed more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a subquery:

```
select date(run_date) as dte,
       1 - count(distinct case when score > 0 then user_id end)) / count(distinct user_id)
from t
group by dte;
```

This counts the number of users who *successfully* ran the game each day.  `1 - <this amount>` is the number who were unsuccessful.